# DBSCAN provided with lines as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dbscan

I am new to both machine learning and python and my goal is to experiment with route prediction through clustering.

I've just started using [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) and I was able to obtain results given an array of coordinates as input to the [fit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.fit) procedure, e.g. [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],...], which includes all coordinates of all routes.

However, what I really want is to provide DBSCAN with a set containing all routes/lines instead of a set containing all coordinates of all routes. Therefore, my question is whether this is possible (does it even make sense?) and if so  how can I accomplish this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If the routes have fixed length, say each route is made of 4 legs (i.e. there are 5 points in a route) then simply provide the route as a 10-dimensional point i.e. `[[x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4,x5,y5], ...]`. If the routes have too many legs you can always decide a common number and split them and feed them as multiple points.

Comment: indeed each route is composed of too many points. Regarding your suggestion won't we loose data? Regarding 10-dimensional points, will it be interpreted correctly (e.g. even numbers are assigned to y-axis and odd ones to x-axis)?

Comment: It depends. You could use a 1billion-dimensional data point and for all routes that are shorter simply repeat the end point up to have that number of dimensions. Sure, you are going to lose information by splitting the routes, however I have no idea what you are trying to do. might or might not be important depending on what exactly you want to achieve. Splitting sequences is a common practice, for example using LSTMs you have to choose a certain number of time steps and divide longer sequences according to that. If you do it well you lose very little information.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think *density* based clustering is a good choice for clustering *routes*? What notion of *density* would you use here?

I'd rather try hierarchical clustering with a proper route distance.

But if you have the **distance matrix** anyway, you *can* of course just try DBSCAN on it for "free" (computing the distances will be *way* more expensive than DBSCAN on a distance matrix).

Comment: I assumed it to be a good choice because I've read multiple papers that use it for route prediction. E.g. here is used for ship route prediction: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Erico_Souza/publication/270884169_Knowledge-based_clustering_of_ship_trajectories_using_density-based_approach/links/5784f3a808aef321de2a86ad/Knowledge-based-clustering-of-ship-trajectories-using-density-based-approach.pdf

Comment: Initially my intuition took me to hierarchical clustering, but I'm not sure how to handle it if the dataset does not include starting coordinates, more specifically, the participants only transmit their location long after the departure (hence I'm missing the trees' root)

Comment: They cluster the points (position, direction and speed), not the routes. So which approach do you want to do? First you need to decide this, then the distance, then the algorithm.